# How to read form fragment references in a pdf document?

Tags: forms, pdf, livecycle

I am working with adobe LiveCycle ES4 and I am attempting to make a custom LiveCycle component (in java) that counts references to a specified form fragment. However I am having some difficulty finding documentation on form fragments in pdf files. So my question is how would I go about reading form fragment references from a pdf document?

Also any documentation, API, or library that may help me with this task would be greatly appreciated.

--Form Fragments--
A form fragment is a collection of form objects (fields, buttons, shapes, tables, etc) as well as related style/formatting that is saved as a separate .xsd file in a form fragment library (usually a directory on the livecycle server that holds the .xsd files). References to form fragments can be inserted into a form when working in LiveCycle Designer.This is particularly useful for creating many similar forms (such as a form fragment with fields for contact information). When a form fragment is edited the changes are reflected across all forms that hold a reference to that fragment (when the pdf is opened and has access to the form fragment library.

Comment: ? The structure of PDF documents is well-defined and available at various websites.

Comment: As you deal with XFA files (and not PDF forms; PDF is just a wrapper around the XFA, so that the file can be opened in Adobe Acrobat/Reader), you might also be able to get something out of the XML part of the XFA file. Otherwise, refer to David van Driessche's answer.

Comment: Your edit indicates that those form fragments indeed are not PDF stuff but XFA related. Whether the information can be extracted from the XFA in the PDF alone or whether you need details from your LC server, might be derived from the XFA specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDF specification currently is an official ISO standard - ISO 32000. You should be able to get the document from the ISO organisation or from your country's standards organisation.

However, before being an ISO standard, PDF was developed and maintained by Adobe and they still have the specification available on their site: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html

There are differences between this specification and the ISO 32000 specification document, but they are largely from an editorial manner so for your purpose I'd look at the Adobe document.

Using the additional information in the comments, your test file and a low level PDF document browser (pdfToolbox in this case - attention, I'm affiliated with this product), I found following information:

In the "Catalog" object for your test PDF, you'll find a key named "AcroForm" that points to a dictionary with information about your form.

In that "AcroForm" dictionary you'll find a key called "XFA" that contains what appears to be almost all information about the XFA form that LifeCycle designer generated.

That "XFA" key points to an array which seems to consist of pairs of information. Element 0 is a string called "preamble", element 1 seems to be the data belonging to that string. So each pair of elements is a bit of information.

The information in that array consists of "preamble", "config", "template", "localeset", "xmpmeta" and "postamble". If you look at the element for "template" (the 6th element in the array if you calculate 1-based), you'll find the data you are looking for. The data is stored as a FlateDecoded stream that you'll have to uncompress - then it's just XML data that should be fairly easy to parse. In it are three lines that for you should be of particular interest:

```
<subform x="6.35mm" y="6.35mm" name="TestFragment1"
<subform x="3.175mm" y="34.925mm" name="TestFragment2"
<subform x="0.125in" y="2.75in" name="TestFragment2"
```

I'm assuming the XFA specification pointed to by mkl contains more information about these things, but it seems like simply looking for "subform" elements in the XML should get you the references to the form fragments pretty easily.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I realize I wasn't clear in my question. I am looking specifically for documentation regarding the use of form fragments in a pdf file. I've seen the documentation you've linked before and although I haven't read it in its entirety it doesn't seem to reference form fragments anywhere.

Comment: I'm afraid we're all a bit lost with what you call "form fragments". Can you be more specific where you have found this referenced? Do you have an example PDF file which shows what you mean or anything like that?

Comment: I've edited the question to include a description of form fragments. I can create pdf files that include form fragments but you won't be able to identify them unless you have Adobe Designer (or ideally know how to read the references programatically in java)

Comment: You can find the XFA specification [here](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/xml/index_arch.html#xfa_33). It mentions *fragments* fairly often.

Comment: Given that you want to get these references from PDF files, this is only going to work if your actual PDF documents contain the information you are looking for somehow. Seeing an example document would still be useful (it's fairly easy to look at the low-level structure in PDF and see if there is something that refers to those form fragments).

Comment: @mkl thanks, I think I've been a little too fixated on the .pdf extension, I've taken a quick look at your link and it seems it may be of some use. Will get back to you when I have more time to actually read through it.

Comment: @David van Driessche I've taken a shot at using apache's PDFBox library to peek at the PDF but I was having trouble figuring out how to read the stream and dictionary objects in a useful way. I have posted an [example pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4ipgJvw_vEPX1U0UnpzTnRKMzg/view?usp=sharing) that has a single reference to a form fragment called TestFragment1 and two references to TestFragment2

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect what I found in your PDF file.

Comment: @goodman_c In addition to the XML elements David mention there also are processing instruction named *designerFragmentSource* in the XFA. That does indicate, though, that those fragments you hunt are not even documented in the XFA specification but are proprietary Livecycle stuff

Comment: Thanks for the help, I accepted your answer because you lead me right to the data I needed. However there is still one thing I'd like to figure out, in the xml for each of the Form Fragments there is an element call designerFragmentSource followed by a long string of (seemingly random) characters, would you happen to have any idea how to decode/read/make sense of that string? here is an example from the pdf for TestFragment1:

Comment: <?designerFragmentSource PHN1YmZvcm0geD0iNi4zNW1tIiB5PSIzLjE3NW1tIiB1c2VocmVmPSIuLlwuLlwuLlxBZG9iZVxB
ZG9iZSBMaXZlQ3ljbGUgRVM0XGZvcm1fZnJhZ21lbnRzXFRlc3RGcmFnbWVudDEueGRwI3NvbSgk
dGVtcGxhdGUuI3N1YmZvcm0uVGVzdEZyYWdtZW50MSkiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnhmYS5v
cmcvc2NoZW1hL3hmYS10ZW1wbGF0ZS8zLjMvIgo+PD90ZW1wbGF0ZURlc2lnbmVyIGV4cGFuZCAx
Pz48L3N1YmZvcm0KPg==?>

Comment: So after some quick reading on xml I realize this is a processing directive and is likely handled by Adobe Designer in some unknown way, but any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: As stated by mkl, use Base64 decoding on that seemingly random string and it'll make a lot more sense. Try www.base64decode.org if you want a quick peek at what it actually says before going through the trouble of implementing it in software

Answer (score 1):

In the XFA xml data in the sample PDF you provided there are processing instructions like this:

```
<?templateDesigner expand 1?><?designerFragmentSource CjxzdWJmb3JtIHVzZWhyZWY9Ii4uXC4uXC4uXEFkb2JlXEFkb2JlIExpdmVDeWNsZSBFUzRcZm9y
bV9mcmFnbWVudHNcVGVzdEZyYWdtZW50MS54ZHAjc29tKCR0ZW1wbGF0ZS5mb3JtMS5UZXN0RnJh
Z21lbnQxKSIgeD0iNi4zNW1tIiB5PSI2LjM1bW0iIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnhmYS5vcmcv
c2NoZW1hL3hmYS10ZW1wbGF0ZS8zLjMvIgo+PD90ZW1wbGF0ZURlc2lnbmVyIGV4cGFuZCAxPz48
L3N1YmZvcm0KPg==?>
```

Decoding the base64 encoded argument in there one gets:

```
<subform usehref="..\..\..\Adobe\Adobe LiveCycle ES4\form_fragments\TestFragment1.xdp#som($template.form1.TestFragment1)" x="6.35mm" y="6.35mm" xmlns="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-template/3.3/"
><?templateDesigner expand 1?></subform
>
```

So it looks like your

> custom LiveCycle component (in java) that counts references to a specified form fragment

should parse the XFA XML, look for these `designerFragmentSource` processing instructions, and analyze them.

Please be aware, though, that these processing instructions most likely are proprietary Adobe stuff (I at least did not find them in the current XFA specification). Thus, as soon some third party tool touches the XFA XML, the PIs might not be accurate anymore. You actually even cannot be sure what happens in different Adobe software versions.